# Karma's base directory location

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Unable to load template fixtures for my tests while using karma. To simplify,

Went to c:\

Created a 1.txt text file.

Made a simple karma init file containing:

```
basePath: '',
```

Started karma using:

```
C:\> karma start .\sample.conf.js
```

Chrome opened up at:

```
http://localhost:9876/?id=49209467
```

I then tried to navigate to:

```
http://localhost:9876/base/1.txt
```

but got a "NOT FOUND" error message in the browser, and a message from karma:

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/1.txt
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10):

Found the answer:

By adding the following to the karma config file:

```
files: [ 
....
{ pattern: 'mocks/**/*.html', watched: true, served: true, included: false },
....
```

I managed to access the required file by browsing to

```
http://localhost:9876/base/mocks/file.html
```

> Where th "`/base/`" prefix is required by default (if even changable).

Comment: Can you explain what that line does?

Comment: @SirBenBenji - It allows Karma to serve up and append the resource mapping for `mocks/file.html` onto whatever is configured for it's `basePath`.  In this case, `basePath` is configured with an empty string so Karma will default to `http://localhost:9876/base`.  So the final result is `http://localhost:9876/base/mocks/file.html`

Comment: If you ever happen to be in Switzerland i'll buy you a beer!! I was on the verge of biting my desk over an issue.

Comment: This is an excellent exchange currency!